# jQuery file is connected but jQuery does not work properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.lead')hide().fadeIn('slow');
    
   
});
```

```css
.lead {
        font-size: 10rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #3fddff;
        text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
    
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-right: 5rem;
        margin-bottom: 6rem;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;        
    }
    
    .webdev {
        font-size: 3rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000;
        text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #aaa;
         
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin-right: 25rem;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;        
    }
    
    .lead {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Title Page</title>
    <!-- Normalize -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="normalize/normalize.css"/>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,900" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
       <br>
       
    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <div class="pos-f-t">
      <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
        <div class="bg-transparent p-4">
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
          <li class="portfolio font-weight-bold">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="about font-weight-bold">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">about</a>
          </li>
          <li class="contact font-weight-bold">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="youtube">
            <a class="nav-link text-danger font-weight-bold" href="#">YouTube Channel (comming soon!)</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-transparent">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- /Nav Bar -->
    
    <h1 class="lead">My Name</h1>
    <p class="webdev">Web Developer</p>
    
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-tA8y0XqiwnpwmOIl3SGAcFl2RvxHjA8qp0+1uCGmRmg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="interact.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hello,

I'm having trouble getting my fadeIn() to work on my page. I am trying to have my name fade-in once my page is loaded but for some reason that does not happen. I know the file is linked properly because I tested it out with a console.log but the fadeIn() does not work at all. I'm pretty new to jQuery but I thought this was one of the more easier functions to do. Am I overlooking something?

Thank you for your help.

Best,
Edwin

Comment: You're missing a `.` - should be this `$('.lead').hide().fadeIn('slow');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `slim` version of jQuery that doesn't include numerous features including animations.

Change `.slim` to `.min` in `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js` if you want full feature set

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

There is also a  typo in

```
$('.lead').hide().fadeIn('slow');
       //^^ missing dot
```

Answer (score 1):

1 check Before you do anything, navigate to your jQuery file and check that it is exactly where it should be.

2load this http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'>

Comment: Please See this first: [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) and [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

None Slim version works fine

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And you can probably remove hide() because you've already hid it using CSS.

```
$('.lead').fadeIn('slow');
```

Double check if jQuery slim has the function fadeIn(), in dev console you probably will see this error (or at least that's what I saw):

> jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:3860 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).fadeIn is
>   not a function TypeError: $(...).fadeIn is not a function
>       ......